# Update Rows of Same table with Non Key Values if Matching rows exists

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables Table1 & Table2

Table1 has following fields

```
Col1(key1)      Col2(key2)      Col3(Key3)      Col4      Col5
000001           A               A1              x1        x2
000001           A               A2                           
000001           A               A3
```

Table2 has following fields

```
Col1(key)       Col2(key)      ColA(key)      ColB(key)   ColC    ColD
000001          A                A1            A2                     
000001          A                A1            A3                     
000001          A                A5            A7
```

I would like to update Col4 and Col5 of Table1 
where Col3 is A2/A3 with values from Col3(A1) as Table2 has ColA as with Values A1/A2 and A1/A3.

Is this Possible in Oracle SQL Update ? I have tried row by row processing. But I think there is a better solution which am unable to figure out.

Desired Result

```
Col1(key1)      Col2(key2)      Col3(Key3)      Col4      Col5
 000001           A               A1              x1        x2
 000001           A               A2              x1        x2  
 000001           A               A3              x1        x2
```

Comment: Table2 has two COLA columns which is impossible so - there's something wrong there.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo